# Converting UTF-16 to UTF-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I've loading a string from a file. When I print out the string with:

```
print my_string
print binascii.hexlify(my_string)
```

I get:

```
2DF5
0032004400460035
```

Meaning this string is `UTF-16`. I would like to convert this string to `UTF-8` so that the above code produces this output:

```
2DF5
32444635
```

I've tried:

```
my_string.decode('utf-8')
```

Which output:

```
32004400460035
```

EDIT:

Here's a quick sample:

```
    hello = 'hello'.encode('utf-16')
    print hello
    print binascii.hexlify(hello)

    hello = hello[2:].decode('utf-8')
    print hello
    print binascii.hexlify(hello)
```

Which produces this output:

```
��hello
fffe680065006c006c006f00
hello
680065006c006c006f00
```

Expected output would be:

```
��hello
fffe680065006c006c006f00
hello
68656c6c6f
```

Comment: That's not exactly a difficult task. What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Also, you have UTF-16 data without a BOM. Judging by the leading nulls you have big-endian UTF-16, but this is probably only partial data? Where does the data come from?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Updated with what I tried. The output is loaded from a file generated by a program on Windows.

Comment: So if the data is encoded to UTF-16, why are you decoding it as UTF-8? Decoding takes bytes and produces a `unicode` object.

Comment: Your output also doesn't make sense in that you are now missing a `00` byte.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is the output, updating now with another sample test.

Comment: You are slicing off the BOM there; the FFFE code unit tells a decoder what order the bytes are to be read in; it'd be FEFF if this was UTF-16 little endian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your string appears to have been encoded using `utf-16be`:

```
In [9]: s = "2DF5".encode("utf-16be")
In [11]: print binascii.hexlify(s)
0032004400460035
```

So, in order to convert it to `utf-8`, you first need to decode it, then encode it:

```
In [14]: uni = s.decode("utf-16be")
In [15]: uni
Out[15]: u'2DF5'

In [16]: utf = uni.encode("utf-8")
In [17]: utf
Out[17]: '2DF5'
```

or, in one step:

```
In [13]: s.decode("utf-16be").encode("utf-8")
Out[13]: '2DF5'
```

Comment: But take into account there could be a BOM in the actual, real-world data.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of `UTF-16be` and that was the issue!

Comment: @Juicy: Note that you *have a BOM* in your actual data; there is no need to pick `be` or `le` when you have a BOM, just decode as UTF-16 *and the BOM is then not part of the decoded value*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, TBH I don't script things like this very often and didn't even know what a BOM is. I'll read up on it for the future!