# Emoji encoding in a XML file with python

Tags: python, xml, encoding

I want to read a XML file into python, but there are a lot of Emojis in it and it seems, that python has a problem with that. I spent the last three days with searching google for that problem, but I could not find an answer.

This is a snippet what my XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<!-- File Created By Signal -->
<smses count="1">
<sms protocol="0" address="+49 0000 00000" date="1456340389816" type="2" subject="null" body="Party! &#55356;&#57225;" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" />
</smses>
```

And this is what my code looks like:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom

file = '/Users/...'
xmldoc = dom.parse(file)
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('sms')
print(len(itemlist))
for s in itemlist:
    print(s.attributes['body'].value)
```

It works for XML files without emojis. But for the example above it fails already in line 4 with reading the file. So I opened the XML file in Visual Studio and it tells me that `&#55356;` and `&#57225;` (which should represent 🎉)are invalide characters. When I replace this both characters with `&#127881;` which is the HTML Entity (decimal) for 🎉 the XML file looks ok, but python still can't read it. Has anyone an idea how to get this script to run?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change those `&#55356` and `&#57225` to a format that Python understands. Those are Unicode characters, here is a link for the explanation of XML unicode: https://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/. For Python, those characters would be `\u5536` and `\u57225`. Here is a post about Unicode and Python: [How to print Unicode character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python).

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the problem. When you convert the expression above into a string like `'Party! \u5536\u57225'` python prints `'Party! 唶圢5'` but this two unicode characters should represent one emoji. This one: . I found out, that the numbers are the utf-16 decimal representation of  but my file is utf-8 encoded. How can I convert the emoji into utf-8?

Comment: @Jan, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207287/converting-utf-16-to-utf-8