# How to convert a utf-16 encoded csv file to utf-8 using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ran few commands like `recode` and iconv but none worked. I think doing this task via Python will surely help.

What should be the appropriate approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207287/converting-utf-16-to-utf-8?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting utf-16 -> utf-8 AND remove BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827419/converting-utf-16-utf-8-and-remove-bom)

Answer (score 3):

## import the libraries

```
import codecs
import shutil

with codecs.open("inputfile.csv", encoding="utf-16") as input_file:
with codecs.open(
        "outputfile.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
```

NB: make sure to read the file with the correct encoding in this case utf-16 as specified in the question and then write it to an output file using the utf-8 encoding sequence.

Answer (score 1):

```
import codecs
import shutil

with codecs.open("input_file.utf8.csv", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
    with codecs.open(
            "output_file.utf16.csv", "w", encoding="utf-16") as output_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
```

Comment: While this snippet can be useful, it would be better to add some details.